# Python module functions to use variables from global env

Tags: python, module, arguments

I'm relatively new to Python and am trying to both do something and learn more about how Python works.

I am coming up empty with google, in part I think because I don't know how to correctly describe what I'm trying to do.

My goal is to load a function from a module, which does not take/require arguments, but finds what it needs in the global environment.

**This works:**

```
temp = 17

def doubletemp():
    dt = temp * 2
    return dt

doubletemp()
```

But if I put doubletemp() in a separate file, called steve.py and have this:

steve.py

```
def doubletemp():
    dt = temp * 2
    return dt
```

dt.py

```
import steve

temp = 17

steve.doubletemp()
```

When I run dt.py, I get an error: NameError: name 'temp' is not defined.

Is there a way around this? A way for the function in Steve.py to look for temp within dt.py's environment?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, using global variables is not really recommended and mostly considered as  bad practice, unless you absolutely have to use them.

In your case, just implement parameter passing. Your first example works, because it's all defined in a single file, but it's still not recommended to do it without parameter passing (what you are doing in the first example).

Do it this way instead:

dt.py

```
    import steve
    temp = 17
    steve.doubletemp(temp)
```

steve.py

```
    def doubletemp(temperature):
        double_temp = temperature * 2
        return double_temp
```

And just so you know, temp and temperature are 2 different variables. Also, if you want to have everything in a single file, it's very much recommended to have parameter passing:

```
    def doubletemp(temperature):
        dt = temperature * 2
        return dt

    temp = 17
    doubletemp(temp)
```

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get it to work correctly this way.

Can you say more about why it is bad practice to use global variables?

The actual end goal here is to have a file path and name defined at the top of multiple scripts, which will be appended by a function.

I'm trying to make it simpler for those using the functions; I'd like to have them just type:
steve.append("text to add to file")

rather than:
steve.append(filepath, "text to add to file")

I'd like to do this for 2 reasons:
1. avoid mistakes due to forgetting syntax
2. avoid errors to to typo of "filepath"

Thanks

Comment: @beginnersluke Global variables can create spaghetti code and introduce hard to find errors problems and build hard to trace interdependencies between multiple files and modules. If your program is simple enough, then you can have a global variable defined and get away with it, but you have to be extra careful to properly access and edit the global variable.
Can you maybe give a simple example of what you are trying to do? If you want to keep it secret, you can give a censored-ish example as well where you rename the variables and just ask what you need without showing the whole program.

Comment: This is for a logging function, basically just append text to an existing file. I was trying to save others on my team the potential mistake of forgetting to include the variable or mistyping the name. TBH, I think it's just getting used to how Python is structured and as I've learned more, which you both helped with here, I actually really like the implementation with parameter passing. Thank you. I just had to wrap my brain around doing things differently than we do in other languages,.

Answer (score 0):

you could use :

```
def doubletemp():
    temp = globals()["temp"]
    dt = temp * 2
    return dt
```

whereby globals() will check your current module, in your case steve.py, but in my opinion this would be a very bad practice. Why don't you just give your variable as parameter in your function, like this :

```
def doubletemp(t):
    return t * 2

**in steve.py** --> doubletemp(temp)
```

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get it to work correctly this way.

Can you say more about why it is bad practice?

The actual end goal here is to have a file path and name defined at the top of multiple scripts, which will be appended by a function.

I'm trying to make it simpler for those using the functions; I'd like to have them just type:
steve.append("text to add to file")

rather than:
steve.append(filepath, "text to add to file")

I'd like to do this for 2 reasons:
1. avoid mistakes due to forgetting syntax
2. avoid errors to to typo of "filepath"

Thanks